# Mac OS X Yosemite Facebook photo posts to OSX Album only

Tags: macos, photos, facebook

The native integration of facebook and Mac OSX Yosemite. I am trying to post a photo with the native integration and the dialog already has "Timeline" Selected but yet it posts to "OS X Photos" album on FB.

How do i configure Mac OS X - to post to my FB timeline? I do not want to post it in an album.

[image: The dialog I see as below. You can see "Timeline" is selected but it still posts into the "OS X Album"]

Answer (score 1):

Photos on Facebook are classified as a album. Every album contains a bunch of pictures. You cannot post images separately to your timeline without having it part of a album.

When you try to post on `facebook.com` as a timeline photo, the images are put into a album called "Timeline Images".

When you post pictures from OS X from the share tab it puts the images in the OS X Photos album. You can manually select another album to post to from the toggle beside the text `Timeline`.

Comment: Yes I know that part, I just want it to post to timeline album. Because I don't want to group the photos. Timeline Photos album pictures doesn't get grouped up (unless you post it in one post)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: you have to drag the chosen photos from Photos app onto your Mac desktop or other location.

They are now duplicates, which you can login to FB and manually upload.

These photos will now ACTUALLY appear in your timeline, not in your old and already commented on MACOS or iOS or OSX etc. album

**Photos app still has the bug whereby the default stated upload folder is "timeline", so this is the expected upload location. However, it always defaults uploads to a different common folder which is not selected by the user, thus *timeline* is never a possible option despite the label.